# How do i portably select rows from a sheet in google docs?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have this snippet `=QUERY(Moto!A1:H, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H where E='Japan'")`
which selects all the rows with "Japan" on the `E` field in a table.

How do i write this in a more "sheets" style, and what can i do to make it work in Excel too? At the moment when downloading the .xlsx file it has the values hard coded and can't change.

Comment: What does a more "sheets" style mean? Then, Excel doesn't have a QUERY function. Maybe FILTER.

Comment: FILTER seems useful but i can't get it to work, it says "mismatched column range sizes" `=FILTER(Moto!A:H, Moto!E="Japan")`

Comment: It seems to work with relative values `=FILTER(Moto!A2:H6, Moto!E2:E6="Japan")`

Comment: Solved `=FILTER(Moto!A2:H, Moto!E2:E="Japan")`

Comment: Right, because Google Sheets range references, e.g. `E2:E`, are different than Excel's, which require an ending row if a start row is provided.